# Calculate number of full time equivalent employees using DAX measures

Tags: sql-server, powerpivot, dax, powerbi

I am able to calculate how many employees are working using DAX measures:

```
Number of employees started := CALCULATE(COUNTA([Emp from]);FILTER(ALL(tDate[Date]);tDate[Date]<=MAX(tDate[Date]))) - 
Number of employees quit := CALCULATE(COUNTA([Emp unitl]);FILTER(ALL(tDate[Date]);tDate[Date]<=MAX(tDate[Date])))
Number of employees working := [Number of employees started] - [Number of employees quit]
```

But I have not managed to calculate how many full time equivalent employees are working. Each employ has a workload from 0% to 100%.

How can I calculate the number of full time equivalent employees?

I have tried the following for number of full time equivalent employees started, but in contrast to the measures above it doesn't accumulate over time. It just shows the results for each individual month:

```
Number of full time equivalent employees started:=CALCULATE(SUMX(tEmployees;tEmployees[Workload]*Not(ISBLANK(tEmployees[Emp from])));FILTER(ALL(tDate[Date]);tDate[Date]<=MAX(tDate[date])))
```

Do you have any suggestion for how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this.  In your Emp table have the start date and end date for the employee.  In your measure you would use the calculatetable function to create an in memory table that has one row for each date in your date table and each employee id.  This same in memory table would take the work percentage and create a column that that represents the number of hours worked by that employee on that day. Then you just need to express number of 'equivalent' employees as: sum of number of hours worked/(number of hours in a 'full time work day' * count of days in period).  This should give you a measure you can use along with your dates to find the number of full time equivalent employees in on any given day or over any given period.

Answer (score 0):

See my sample table structure in [this TechNet forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37d70134-55b5-4160-a17f-fc9351635307/headcount-analysis-and-many-to-many-type-2-slowly-changing-dimensions?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel). This is a modelling problem first, and a DAX problem second.

Once you've created your headcount fact, all of this becomes trivial.